# Pattern Substitution in Haxe

Tags: regex, haxe

```
var str2 : String = "Expander Detected (%MSG_ID%)";
var r2 = ~/[\(%MSG_ID%\)]+/g;
trace(r2.replace(str2, ""));
```

Expected Result: `Expander Detected`

Actual Result: `Expander etected`

I need to replace `(%MSG_ID%)` in my strings. Characters before `(%MSG_ID%)` are dynamic, so we can not replace them manually.

Comment: Actually you can simply do `StringTools.replace('(%MSG_ID%)','')`

Comment: It gives below given error:
Test.hx:6: characters 14-26 : String has no field replace

Comment: Oh sorry it should be `trace(StringTools.replace(str2,'(%MSG_ID%)',''))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the surrounding `[]`. This works as expected:

```
var r2 = ~/\(%MSG_ID%\)+/g;
```

`[]` is a character set which matches if a *single* character contained in the set matches. Since the set happens to contain `D`, the `D` is also removed when calling `replace()`. However, you only want to match if all characters (and in that order) are present.

I'd recommend a tool like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qo6k25/1) for testing regexes. You can nicely see the issue there:

[image]